# Silex: user form with custom authenticator

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, silex

I'm trying to build custom authentication system for my Silex application.

The idea is that all authentication will be done by separate service. I spent a day trying to get into Silex\Symfony authentication mechanism, but cannotsay that I did well :-\ 
I found this [Custom Authentication System with Guard](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/cookbook/guard_authentication.html) tutorial which worked at basic for me. Using it as a basement I started to adopt it for my needs.
It worked until I tried to add *form* bit.

For the moment my main problem is that it do not (or I do not understand how to do this) redirects to login URL when trying to access secured area. I found a workaround by putting hardcoded redirect into *TokenAuthenticator->start()* method, but it smells really bad for me. Besides, in that case, it do not redirects to initially requested URL after successful authentication.

Can someone hint me what is wrong in my code (beside doing it without full understanding of how mechanism works ;) or, at least, describe Silex authentication flow (from requesting secured URL till redirect after success auth)? Keep in mind that I'm absolutely unfamiliar with Symfony so their manuals are not really helpful for me.

my code:

**index.php**

```
<?
// bootstrap stuff here...

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app->get('/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.twig', array(
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
});

$app['app.token_authenticator'] = function ($app) {
    return new \CP\Classes\TokenAuthenticator($app['security.encoder_factory']);
};

$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
    'secured' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/safe/',
        'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/safe/login_check'),
        'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/safe/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
        'guard' => array(
            'authenticators' => array(
                'app.token_authenticator'
            ),
        ),
        'users' => function () use ($app) {
            return new \CP\Classes\OMSUserProvider($app);
        },
    ),
);

$app->register( new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider() );

// blablabla 
$app->run();
```

**TokenAuthenticator.php**

```
<?php

namespace CP\Classes;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;

class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator {
    private $encoderFactory;

    public function __construct( EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory ) {
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
    }

    public function getCredentials( Request $request ) {
        $username = $request->request->get('_username');
        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $username);
        $password = $request->request->get('_password');

        return array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
        );
    }

    public function getUser( $credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider ) {
        return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername( $credentials['username'] );
    }

    public function checkCredentials( $credentials, UserInterface $user ) {
        $res = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:83/auth.php?u='.$user->getUsername().'&p='.$credentials['password']));

        return $res->result;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess( Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey ) {
        return;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure( Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception ) {
        $data = [ 'message' => strtr( $exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData() )];

        return new JsonResponse( $data, 403 );
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent
     */
    public function start( Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null ) {
//      Mentioned hardcoded redirect
//      $app = new \Silex\Application();
//      return $app->redirect('/login', 401);

        $data = [ // you might translate this message
                  'message' => 'Authentication Required', ];

        return new JsonResponse( $data, 401 );
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: tip if you want to understand it you need to read and understand chapter about security component in symfony

Comment: @Robert
I really keen to understand it, but 
a) I need to solve the above mentioned in quite a limited time (that is why I'm begging for help here)
b) Symfony is a bit different from Silex in terms of gathering these bits together and I have no time to get deep into Simfony, Alas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not a full answer, here are some thoughts:

1. You should really try to understand the Security Component. The best way for me was to create a simple application (2 pages: login form and secured area), and go through a step by step debugger. Also I really liked this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1y6fxetP5k&list=PLo7mBDsRHu12SbjRS_botIIdJ51zU0FxP&index=11
2. No, Symfony and Silex security are not that different. The main difference is the configuration part
3. Your implementation is quite right, but creating a new instance of Application does not make sense. Your service only requires the redirection URL, which you can inject:

**TokenAuthenticator.php**

```
<?php

//...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    private $encoderFactory;

    private $login_url

    public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory , $login_url = '/login')
    {
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
        $this->login_url = $login_url;
    }

    //...

    /**
     * Called when authentication is needed, but it's not sent
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->login_url, 401);
    }

    //...
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

//...
$app->get('/login', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.twig', array(
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
})->bind('login');

//...

$app['app.token_authenticator'] = function ($app) {
    return new \CP\Classes\TokenAuthenticator(
        $app['security.encoder_factory'],
        $app['url_generator']->generate('login')
    );
};

//...
```